# About forms and instance

Tags: django

Sometimes, I have to display multiple checkbox to check or uncheck some items. So the form could have some checkbox already checked. To do this, I use `form = myform(instance=manyTomanyField)`.

The problem here, I can't do it because my many to many field has a `through` parameter :

```
games = models.ManyToManyField(Games, through="Relation" verbose_name="Jeu")
```

Indeed, I'm using `through="Relation"`.

I have no error message, but no checkbox are checked. Normally I should have all checked by default.

views.py :

```
def view_team_recruitment(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        media = settings.MEDIA

        form = TeamRecruitmentForm(instance=Team.objects.get(owner=request.user))
```

Models.py :

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=False)
    description = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True, default='')
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Games, through="Relation", verbose_name="Jeu")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Créateur", related_name='myteam')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Relation(models.Model):
    on_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name="Equipe")
    on_game = models.ForeignKey(Games, verbose_name="Jeu")
    on_plateform = models.ForeignKey(Plateform, verbose_name="Plateforme")
    recruitment = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Plateform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="Plateforme")
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="Abréviation")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Games(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, verbose_name="GUID")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="Titre")
    logo = models.FileField(upload_to='media/games/', validators=[validate_file_extension], blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Logo du jeu")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de création")
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Dernière modification")
    plateform = models.ManyToManyField(Plateform, verbose_name="Plateforme")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class TeamRecruitmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    game = Games.objects.all()
    recruitment = GamesChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=game, required=False)  

    class Meta:
        model = Relation
        fields = ('recruitment', )
```

What I want is simple, for now, the render is :
[image]

And I want to check any boxes according to my model. In general, my method works with a simple Many To Many field...

Thank you all

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to pass `.....games` as the instance. That's a field.

Comment: Language off-topic: why do you mix French and English for class names? If you already have started with English, be consistent throughout your whole project. Use `Platform` instead of `Plateform`, which is by the way not even correct French (it should be `Plateforme`).

Comment: @cezar Just a simple english orthograph mistake.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman You're right. I don't have any error message but still doesn't work. (I update my code). I have no checkboxes checked and normally I should have all checked by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query:

```
qv = Team.objects.get(owner=request.user)
instance = Relation.objects.filter(on_team=qv.id)

def view_team_recruitment(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        media = settings.MEDIA

        form = TeamRecruitmentForm(instance=Team.objects.get(owner=request.user))
```

Your form works with model : Relation and in your instance query is: Team

```
form = TeamRecruitmentForm(instance=Team.objects.get(owner=request.user))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think there no solution like I want. It seems according to the django doc, if there is a "through" relationship for a Many To Many field, so we always have to do any operation manualy.